# Wrong name and FIDE ID in rated classical tournament

Tags: fide, tournament

I am play in a classical, FIDE rated event. I entered via my coach. I just gave him my name and said I don't have a FIDE id. When I was playing my first game I noticed that my name is wrong. They added a third name with my first and second name and there was a FIDE id also whereas I don't have any FIDE ID yet (that was another person's FIDE ID).

I talked with arbiter and the one who is working on computer to input data in chess-results.com. They told me to correct the mistake in the sheet (they gave a team-chart to every table). I had talked about it two times. And noticed that nothing had changed in chess-results.com (the name is as before and the FIDE ID isn't removed yet).

The tournament is about to finish. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: That's not actually my coach, I didn't get any lesson from him. He is just a coach.

Answer (score 4):

> when I was in the game I noticed that my name is wrong, they added third name with my first and second name and there was FIDE id also whereas I don't have any FIDE ID yet (that was another person's FIDE ID).

So what happened was this.

The arbiter setting the tournament up in the pairing program Swiss Manager got to the "enter players" stage, brought up the right screen, entered your last name and hit enter. The program then searched in the copy of the FIDE rating database, which it had previously downloaded, for players matching your last name. It probably found several and presented them to the arbiter who saw one of them with a first name that matched your first name. He clicked on that and that was added to the list of players for the tournament.

> And noticed that nothing had changed in chess-results.com (the name is as before and the FIDE ID isn't removed yet).

Chess-results.com is nothing to do with FIDE. It is the website associated with the Swiss Manager pairing program. Stuff changes on chess-results.com when the arbiter presses the button in Swiss Manager which says "Update to internet" or something similar. The program then sends the current state of the tournament in Swiss Manager on the arbiter's computer to the website which then updates the information it holds.

You will see nothing on chess-results until the arbiter changes the details in Swiss Manager. They won't do this until they have your date of birth because FIDE require your DoB to enter you in their database.

FIDE will know nothing about this until the end of the tournament when the arbiter / organizer sends the TRF (tournament report form) to the governing federation and they send it on to FIDE. As part of this process the governing federation will assign new FIDE ids for all new players in the tournament from the range of ids that FIDE has given that federation to use.

You need to make sure that the arbiter has your date of birth else nothing much is going to change. Your coach is also partly to blame because they should also know these kinds of things and should have spoken to you about it before the tournament.

Comment: 1. They have a DoB which they found in FIDE, I saw there's 4 account in FIDE with my first and second name but they all had third name which I didn't have. <br/> 2. I don't think coach should be blamed cause he told me to visit the place where the tournament is organized and I was also in one of his tournament which ended late evening that's why I couldn't visit because I was tired so I just called him and he set up everything.  <br/> 3. I can't really search my answer in your question, but what I understood that is : now I have to tell them I don't have FIDE ID and my DoB is something else.

Comment: I just heard about the tournament the day before the tournament started. FYI I have already given the DoB, "they told me to give". Since I saw nothing changed that's I was worried a bit.